# How to detect Desktop vs. Mobile vs. GearVR vs. Oculus Rift vs. Vive in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

In A-Frame, I want to detect if the user has a VR headset connected and to tell which device they are using. How can I do this?

- Desktop (no VR display)
- Mobile (e.g., webvr-polyfilled Google Cardboard, iPhone, Android)
- Samsung GearVR
- Oculus Rift
- HTC Vive

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several utility functions in A-Frame we can use to detect compatibility: https://aframe.io/docs/master/core/utils.html

The mobile-related utils look at `navigator.userAgent`. The VR-related utils check to see if the pose data returned from the headset/polyfill is not 0,0,0.

Given the current API:

- Desktop: `!AFRAME.utils.checkHeadsetConnected()`
- Mobile: `AFRAME.utils.isMobile()`
- GearVR: `AFRAME.utils.isGearVR()`
- Oculus Rift: `!AFRAME.utils.isMobile() && AFRAME.utils.checkHeadsetConnected()`
- HTC Vive: `!AFRAME.utils.isMobile() && AFRAME.utils.checkHeadsetConnected()`

To differentiate Rift vs. Vive, try using WebVR API Stage Parameters https://w3c.github.io/webvr/#interface-vrstageparameters

Comment: Note in 0.4.0, these utils will be moving to `AFRAME.utils.device`

Comment: Code here : https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/utils/device.js