# How do I detect a user's browser with A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

Presently, I have a Rails CMS that allows a user to upload an image. Before saving it to the database, the page displays a 2D preview of their image. After saving, the preview is removed and the image is instead rendered to the user as a 3D panorama inside an iframe.

Ideally, I would like to create a whitelist of browsers that allow the user to view the saved image as a 3D panorama - otherwise the image remains 2D.

My question is that, given A-Frame does not support Internet Explorer (and potentially earlier versions of other browsers), how do I detect which specific browser a user is viewing the website with?

I've read through the [Utils documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/master/core/utils.html) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984951/how-to-detect-desktop-vs-mobile-vs-gearvr-vs-oculus-rift-vs-vive-in-a-frame) on device detection, however neither yield any insights.

Any advice would be appreciated :)

Comment: As a heads up, for both cleanliness and intuitiveness I ended up using the Ruby Gem ["Browser"](https://github.com/fnando/browser).

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigator.userAgent to determine browser information. Tons of utilities for it online, not only specific to A-Frame.

A-Frame has several utilities, currently not documented:

`AFRAME.utils.isMobile`

`AFRAME.utils.isIOS`

`AFRAME.utils.isGearVR`